# CPUs to process lidar data using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, lidar, hardware-recommendations, multithreading

I am looking to build a computer to process data in ArcGIS 10.2.2.

The main use will be to rasterize 10-100's GBs of lidar data.

However, I am unclear as to the capabilities of ArcGIS 10.2.2 to utilize hyper-threading and multiple cores. In prior iterations of ArcGIS, I remember that only some geoprocessing tools could utilize this added computational capability. I am therefore trying to decide between the Intel Core i5-4690K and i7-4690K.

Does anyone have any experince with these processors and ArcGIS 10.2.2? Even better, does anyone have experience with these cores for lidar data processing?

Comment: It is still the case that only some tools can use multiple threads/cores. I'm not sure if there is a comprehensive list anywhere, as 'mosaicking' seems to be the most common example cited. I did see in some searching that there is an [environment setting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Parallel_Processing_Factor/001w0000004m000000/) (neither PtoR or FtoR list that setting as relevant) and you can write your own code to take advantage of multiple processors, but there were [issues with implementation](http://www.husseinnasser.com/2014/10/multi-threading-and-arcgis.html).

Comment: What specific LiDAR processing are you hoping to accomplish?  Most folks who work with LiDAR do not use ArcGIS for working with LiDAR data.  Two packages that are great for working with LiDAR are LasTools (commercial) and FUSION (free), both of which can utilize the full potential of your cores. I find that being I/O bound is the biggest limiting factor when working with LiDAR data. If you can get a machine with a PCI SSD for caching and a large number of cores, you will be in good shape.  If you have the choice between i5 and i7, always go i7.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the response. I need to filter county wide lidar datasets for ground points and then grid them. I really like LAStools, but even as a student I haven't been able to afford them for my research. As for FUSION, I haven't been able to find a good cookbook. Do you know of one?

Comment: FUSION has really good documentation.  You can use a combination of GroundFilter and GridSurfaceCreate to produce a ground surface model.  You may want to consider opening a new question for this topic.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: About Fusion's GroundFilter, take a look [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blidar%5D+groundfilter) before asking, so you can narrow the question (if you get to ask it). Tks.